# Importing python script and passing arguments to run within a different script

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, arguments

So I have my main python script which I run and essentially pass three arguments that are `-p`, -`e` and `-d` to another python script. I have been using `subprocess` in order to this which I understand.

What I want to achieve is rather than using `subprocess` I want to `import` the second file `'generate_json.py'`,  and be able to pass the three arguments to its `main()` function. How can I pass the three arguments like I have in my `subprocess` call?

My code for my main script is as follows:

```
import generate_json as gs


def get_json_location(username=os.getlogin()):
    first = "/Users/"
    last = "/Desktop/data-code/Testdata"
    result = first + username + last
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the script files do not have to be used individually, i.e: `generate_json.py` on its own from the command line.

I think a cleaner approach would be to wrap `generate_json.py` functions and put it into a class.

In this case I renamed `generate_json.py` to `ConfigurationHandling.py`

```
import os
import json
from functions import read_config

class ConfigurationHandler(object):
    def __init__(self, new_parameter_file, new_export_data_file, new_export_date):
        self._parameter_file = new_parameter_file
        self._export_data_file = new_export_data_file
        self._export_date = new_export_date
        self._parsed_configuration = self.read_configuration()

        self._perform_some_action1()
        self._perform_some_action2()

    def _read_configuration(self):
        """Uses lower level function `read_config` in function.py file to read configuration file"""
        parsed_configuration = read_config(self.export_data_file)
        return parsed_configuration

    def _perform_some_action1(self):
        pass

    def _perform_some_action2(self):
    #     Logic code for parsing goes here.
        pass

    def get_config(self):
        """Returns configuration"""
        return [self.parameter_file, self.parsed_configuration, self.export_date]


    def json_work(self):
        cfg = self.get_config()[0]  # json location
        data = self.get_config()[1]  # export_agent_core_agent.yaml
        date = self.get_config()[2]  # synthetic data folder - YYYY-MM-DD

        if not date:
            date = ""
        else:
            date = date + "/"

        json_location = cfg  # json data path
        json_database = data["config"]["database"]
        json_collection = data["config"]["collection"]
        json_path = "{0}/{1}{2}/{3}/{3}.json".format(json_location, date, json_database, json_collection)
        json_base_name = json_database + "/" + json_collection + "/" + os.path.basename(json_path)  # prints json filename
        current_day = date


        with open('dates/' + current_day + '.json', 'a') as file:
            data = {}


            if os.path.exists(json_path):
                json_file_size = str(os.path.getsize(json_path))  # prints json file size
                print("File Name:" " " + json_base_name + " " "Exists " + "\n")
                print("File Size:" " " + json_file_size + " " "Bytes " "\n")
                print("Writing to file")
                # if json_path is not False:
                data['File Size'] = int(json_file_size)
                data['File Name'] = json_base_name
                json.dump(data, file, sort_keys=True)
                file.write('\n')

            else:
                print(json_base_name + " " "does not exist")
                print("Writing to file")
                data['File Name'] = json_base_name
                data['File Size'] = None
                json.dump(data, file, sort_keys=True)
                file.write('\n')

        file.close()
```

Then in `main.py`

```
from ConfigurationHandler import ConfigurationHandler

def main():
    #Drive the program from here and add the functionality together.
    #Routine to do some work here and get the required variables
    parameter_file = "some_parameter"
    export_data_file = "some_file.yaml"
    new_export_date = "iso_8601_date_etc"

    conf_handl = ConfigurationHandler(parameter_file, export_data_file, new_export_date)
    configuration = conf_handl.get_config()
    conf_handl.json_work()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In the project, you should aim to have only one main function and split up the functionality accordingly.

It will be much easier to change parts of the program later on when everything is split out evenly.

Comment: I can understand what you are trying to do , however my generate_json file has more functionality within , where it will be looping through each file in a directory and assigning that to export_data_file.  I have updated my generate_json file above in the question. This main.py will need to run via arguments on the command line. It will be running on the command line with the argument -p , -e and -d

Comment: Only the command line argument -d sorry , -p and -e will be set

Comment: If you need more functionality, you could add another function within the class for that specific work you are looking for. Hope this helps. But I don't think using a `main` function per file is the correct approach. Rather than sending arguments you could send a map of the commands needed.

Comment: right ok. Thanks for your help. I will try this and see what i get

Comment: it actually wont work , as the arguments in get_config will be passed in to variables. If you take a look at my question i have updated my code

Comment: So inside, the Handler , I added another function to do more work and write to file. The main then only has to call `instance.json_work`

Comment: I have got to work it , but i am having one small issue. Within main.py  , if i pass a file name to export_data_file it will work. I want to be able to loop through each file in the yml directory but i get an issue saying error reading_config file. i am doing the following if you look at my comment below

Comment: It actually doesn't seem to be picking up the json location and writing an empty path @r1024

Comment: I think you should get the functions working individually such as file reading and parsing independently. Then arrange them together. I am not sure how much further I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

So far i have got the following :

```
from genrate_jsonv2 import ConfigurationHandler
import os
import argparse

def get_json_location(username=os.getlogin()):
    first = "/Users/"
    last = "/Desktop/data-code/Testdata"
    result = first + username + last
    return result

def get_config():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-d", "--export-date", action="store", required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    return [args.export_date]

yml_directory = os.listdir('yaml')
yml_directory.remove('export_config.yaml')
data = get_config()[0]

def main():

 for yml in yml_directory:
    parameter_file = get_json_location
    export_data_file = yml
    new_export_date = data

    conf_handl = ConfigurationHandler(parameter_file, export_data_file, new_export_date)
    configuration = conf_handl.get_config()
    conf_handl.json_work()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The issue is , within export_data_file , i don't really want to be passing a file_path location , i rather have it loop through each file_name in the yml directory. When doing so i get an error saying ,'Error reading config file'